# Does this component exist? On/off switch in the shape of a rotary pot?

Tags: switches, potentiometer

I've looked for this, it probably doesn't exist.

I'd like to acquire a latching on/off switch in the physical form of a common 3-leg potentiometer.  Rotate the knob one way to turn the switch off (break circuit), rotate it the other way to turn the switch on (continuity).  Ideally I'd like to solder it to a PCB in place of an existing 3-leg pot and have the shaft stick through the hole that the pot shaft currently does.  Any ideas?

Comment: Look for "Rotary Switch".  They usually have several positions, but rotation can be limited as required.  I doubt if you will find one that will physically replace a pot, however.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. They are called rotary switches.  There are lots of such devices, especially with high pin counts 6 pos 2 way, 2 pos 6 way, 3 pos 4 way, etc,

Here is a picture of one on sale from Digikey for wire connection, but they have many which can be directly PCB mounted.  Just search for "Rotary Switch".

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Potentiometers with on/off switches do exist. They were used as volume and on/off switches in old car radios. They just have the off position at far left position and then they click and are on for the rest of the pot travel.

Also, rotary switches may work for you, they generally are a bit larger than potetiometers with on/off switch.